# Moving WP site to another Domain. Images and content missing

Tags: php, wordpress

I developed a wordress site at: http://acenetsolution.com/activelearningwp/

I have manually moved the site to: http://activelearningpartnersltd.com/ on a different server.

But now, i can't see any images on the site and content is missing. However, pages are working fine.

I can see all the images are uploaded on server but they are not displaying.

When i upload a new image in wordpress the URL for the image comes as: `http://activelearningpartnersltd.com/home/activey2/public_html/activelearningpartnersltd.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/logo-1.png`

It should be like: http://activelearningpartnersltd.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/logo-1.png

My widgets are also not displaying in wp-admin.

Anything i did wrong?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.billerickson.net/how-to-move-your-wordpress-website/) tutorial, it'll help you.

Comment: It seems you didn't move database correctly. That's why images path are wrong.

Comment: @Milap what could be wrong with it? I imported the tables one after another. Now why does it showing domain path? What got wrong?

Comment: @SahibjotSingh, just check `SITE_URL` and other urls in database. It may be wrong.

Comment: @Milap Just checked it. Everything is updated to http://activelearningpartnersltd.com

Answer (score 0):

Use This process

1. download your server database file.
2. now open your database file in notepad++ editor
3. now find "http://acenetsolution.com/activelearningwp/" and replace url = "http://activelearningpartnersltd.com/" replace all

now upload this database on server

Comment: when i upload an image. Why does it show domain path in wp-admin?